# Android Studio 2.1.x Printing default font name

Tags: android, printing, fonts, default

I would like to print some code files with Android Studio.
Before I've changed the font Name in the print file Dialog.
But the different font did not fit my needs.

What is the Default font name for printing?

Or what font name do you prefer for printing code on paper?

Answer (score 0):

There are two fonts I really like for code:
Deja Vu Sans Mono which you can download for free here --> http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Download

Source Code Pro which you can download for free here --> https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/source-code-pro

You may also want to check out this top 10 list of free code fonts: http://hivelogic.com/articles/top-10-programming-fonts/

Now, for the default Android Studio font:
I believe it is 'Monospaced'
[image]